# TCL code to loop through a string and print only value greater than

Tags: string, loops, match, tcl

A file consists of multiple input strings that consist of a fixed letter "a" followed by [0-15], space, and then a decimal value. Each of these sets is enclosed in curly braces and separated by the next set by a space. I'm looking for the set where the decimal value exceeds 5.0000 but dropping the highest value which is 113.1600 (first line) and 208.1150 (second line). For eg. Output of the first string will be {a7 32.7832} & no output for second string.

Input:

```
{a7 32.7832} {a8 1.6795} {a9 0.4920} {a10 0.6235} {a11 0.4190} {a14 3.2500} {a6 1.5170} {a12 0.2620} {a13 0.0410} {a3 2.6730} {a4 2.7620} {a5 0.7490} {a2 2.0300} {a15 113.1600}
{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 1.4035} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}
{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 6.0835} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}
```

Output:

```
{a7 32.7832}
{a8 6.0835}
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, Tcl and Perl are different languages. And it's not like C and C++ where they're at least superficially similar. Tcl and Perl are *very* different languages.

Comment: Yes, corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out. I was looking for either or solution - whichever is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do in TCL as strings enclosed in brackets are treated as lists. Then you just loop over all the value, skip anything less than 5, and build a list of everything that isn't the highest values.

```
set values {{a7 32.7832} {a8 1.6795} {a9 0.4920} {a10 0.6235} {a11 0.4190} {a14 3.2500} {a6 1.5170} {a12 0.2620} {a13 0.0410} {a3 2.6730} {a4 2.7620} {a5 0.7490} {a2 2.0300} {a15 113.1600}}

set values2 {{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 1.4035} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}}

set values3 {{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 6.0835} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}}


proc calcValues {values} {
    set outputs [list]
    set max {}

    foreach value $values {
        set num [lindex $value 1]

        if {$num < 5.0} {
            continue
        }

        if {$max eq {}} {
            set max $value
            continue
        }

        if {[lindex $max 1] < $num} {
            lappend outputs $max
            set max $value
        } else {
            lappend outputs $value
        }
    }

    return $outputs
}

puts [calcValues $values]
puts [calcValues $values2]
puts [calcValues $values3]
```

Comment: The first element of the list needn't be max value. Edited the question to show more examples. There might be a case where there is nothing greater than 5.0 (except the greatest numerical value which we are anyway ignoring)

Comment: @user8217644 You are right, I completely forgot to account for the initial value being less than 5. I've fixed it

Comment: Thanks Samuel! Would this be time-effective if I have a long file with such strings or a collection of strings assigned to a variable?

Comment: TCL is pretty efficient with lists, so this should run pretty well. There are probably ways to optimize it, but that would take profiling and more TCL knowledge than I have.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are definitely Tcl lists; the format is constrained enough that we can say that that must be true. Which makes it easy; no significant data conditioning step required! You can use `lsort -real -index 1` to sort the pairs of the list by their floating point values; the second element in the sorted list will be the one you are looking for... provided it is above the threshold.

```
foreach line [split $inputData "\n"] {
    # Get the pair with the second-highest value in the list
    set target [lindex [lsort -real -index 1 $line] 1]
    # Test against the threshold
    if {[lindex $target 1] >= 5.0} {
        puts $target
        # Could also lappend the target to a result list here
        # You didn't say how you wanted the results
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set lines {
    {{a7 32.7832} {a8 1.6795} {a9 0.4920} {a10 0.6235} {a11 0.4190} {a14 3.2500} {a6 1.5170} {a12 0.2620} {a13 0.0410} {a3 2.6730} {a4 2.7620} {a5 0.7490} {a2 2.0300} {a15 113.1600}}
    {{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 1.4035} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}}
    {{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 6.0835} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}}
}

set maxima [lmap line $lines {
    set sorted [lsort -real -index 1 $line]
    set second_max [lindex $sorted end-1]
    if {[lindex $second_max end] <= 5.0} then continue else {set second_max}
}]
```

result

```
{a7 32.7832} {a8 6.0835}
```

Answer (score 0):

Original question asked for Perl  or TCL, so here is a possible Perl solution

```
my @lines = (
    "{a7 32.7832} {a8 1.6795} {a9 0.4920} {a10 0.6235} {a11 0.4190} {a14 3.2500} {a6 1.5170} {a12 0.2620} {a13 0.0410} {a3 2.6730} {a4 2.7620} {a5 0.7490} {a2 2.0300} {a15 113.1600}",
    "{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 1.4035} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}", 
    "{a3 1.0995} {a5 0.3180} {a6 0.3395} {a7 0.5600} {a8 6.0835} {a9 1.1810} {a10 0.4340} {a11 0.3430} {a13 0.6970} {a14 208.1150} {a2 1.4630} {a4 1.0820}",
);


for my $line (@lines)
{
    my @data;
    print "\nnew data\n";

    # read & parse input data
    while ($line =~ /{(a\d+)\s+([\d\.]+?)}/g)
    {
        # don't want values less than 5
        next if $2 <= 5;

        # remember the values parsed
        push @data, [$1, $2];
    }

    # sort by the number
    @data = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @data;

    # don't want the biggest, so remove it
    pop @data;

    # now have the data to output
    print join " ", map { "{@$_}"   } @data ;
    print "\n" ;
}
```

outputs

```
new data
{a7 32.7832}

new data


new data
{a8 6.0835}
```